# How is Faltings Theorem related to Convolution?

Tags: convolution

Convolution has been put synonymous to falting [B. S. Grewal](https://www.amazon.in/Higher-Engineering-Mathematics-B-S-Grewal/dp/8193328493), Ed. 44, p.p. 748 ; which I now know (after Googling) comes from the faltings's theorem. But the relation is not well explained neither in the book nor on the web.

Comment: This makes no sense... What *exactly* does the book say?

Comment: Are you asking about a theorem due to  [Gerd Faltings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_Faltings), or about  what in German is known as ["Faltung"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltung_(Mathematik)) and in English, as "Convolution"?

Comment: And aren't you confusing "Faltings's Theorem" with the "Faltung theorem"?

Comment: @HansLundmark , The words are quoted as under:
"F*G is called the **Convolution** or **falting** of F and G"

Comment: @kimchilover I could be wrong with the _Faultings's Theorem_ part. But most certainly I am writing the spelling printed in the book. However, Googling your term **Faltung Theorem** , there is strong possibility of a misprint. Can't be sure on that, hence the question.

Comment: Obviously a typo in your book.  It should read "Convolution or faltung of $F$ and $G$."

Comment: If the book is from 1965 (as stated in your link), it would have predated Faltings's theorem. Gerd Faltings himself would have been 11 years old in 1965. Which is to say that I think the connection you've found is a red herring, and that the German "Faltung" (or maybe even the Swedish "faltning") at some point turned into "falting".